# Android Studio emulator not working / has terminated / timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I've downloaded Android Studio and created a new project.
And when I've tried it with the emulator, I was getting this error.

**launching 'app' on pixel 4 api 30. error while waiting for device: timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.**

Then, I've unistalled the application and downloaded again the last version.

Now, when I'm trying to test the application and run the Android emulator, I get the following error.

**Launching 'app' on pixel 4 api 32. error while waiting for device: the emulator process for avd pixel_4_api_32 has terminated.**

I've tried a lot of solutions that I found online but nothing seems to be working.

I'm on Windows 10 and have a Dell Inspiron 15 PC.

Could you guys help find the solution?

Comment: have you found any solution for that?

Comment: No, I have not.